# Understanding $D \partial^2 P(x,v,t)/\partial x^2$ as a type of collision term

Tags: diffusion, stochastic-processes, boltzmann-equation, transport-phenomena

Using conservation of particles in a control volume in phase space (in one dimension with no sources of particles or external forces), one can derive the formal transport equation
$$ \partial_t P(x,v,t) = - v \partial_x P + \mathcal{I}(x,v,t) $$
for the density of particles having position $x$ and velocity $v$ at time $t$. (See for example http://milproj.dc.umich.edu/pdfs/books/1979%20Transport%20Theory.pdf) In this equation, $\mathcal{I}(x,v,t)$ is some term representing (generally nonlocal) scattering processes. For gas particles, it's the Boltzmann collision integral. For a plasma particles, it has some form involving coulomb/lorentz interactions, and so on.

One also has the standard advection-diffusion equation for particles traveling at velocity $v$ with a Gaussian white noise force -- $m \dot{v} = \sqrt{2D}\xi(t)$. This leads to the governing equation
$$ \partial_t P(x,v,t) = -v \partial_x P + D \partial_x^2 P.$$
Here the term involving $D$ is a standard diffusion term.

My question is: how to reconcile these two equations? What type of collision term in the formal transport equation corresponds to Gaussian white noise driving forces at the scale of individual particles?